# Information from passenger list/ship manifest from 1912 NY - Polish/Russian city and names

Tags: palaeography, poland, russia, manifest, place-names

The full passenger list can be found below – I'm looking at the entry for "Jankel Samolicz" on line 30 (the final line). Can you help me to read some of the information? I'm trying to figure out:

- the precise spelling of the name and surname;
- city of last permanent residence;
- relation, name, and address of relative in home country;
- relation and name of relative in the US (the US address is known/not important);
- city of birth

The address of relative in home country and city of birth/last permanent residence are of particular interest to me, but I can't seem to find the city or tell the proper spelling. As far as I know, this person was from the area of Liuboml/Lyuboml in the Volhynia region in present-day Ukraine (part of Poland in the interwar period, and part of the Russian Empire before World War I).

[image: Passenger list - page 1]
[image: Passenger list - page 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read:

- Name: Samolicz Jankel
- Age etc.: 20 Yrs, male, single
- Occupation: Setler [?]
- can read and write
- Country of Origin and Race: Russia, Heb
- Last residence: Russia, Omriau
- Relative: sister Bluma Samolicz Amriau Wolin [?]
- Destination: New York
- Ticket? yes
- Passage paid by: father
- Money: no
- never been in the U.S. before
- joining father Liser [?] Samolicz New York 156. Garrick av.
- 5 ft. 5 in. tall
- fr. [fair]
- Color of hair: br[own]
- Color of eyes: br[own]
- Place of birth: Russia, Omoriau

I'm quite sure of the spelling of the birth place (checked A against O etc.) but I was not able to find a matching place so far.

Answer (score 1):

In the Lithuanian and Polish families I grew up around, a word that sounds almost like the words you use for To Polish, like polish a table. 
Perhaps their language skills were not very good at the time, and they were trying to say they were from Polish Russia?
One of my relatives is actually listed in Ellis Island as coming from Cracked Cow, Poland... He was from Kracow

Comment: Which word are you referring to?

Comment: Omoriau.. as spelled above, is used in several slavic languages, in various spellings, to say Polish, as Polish a table.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a territory that misspeled in the Russian Empire
Russia, Omriau
Amriau Wolin
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volhynia

Volhynia (also spelled Volynia) (/voʊˈlɪniə/ voh-LIN-ee-ə; Ukrainian: Воли́нь, romanized: Volýnʹ, Polish: Wołyń, Russian: Волы́нь, romanized: Volýnʹ, Yiddish: װאָלין, romanized: Volin), is a historic region in Central and Eastern Europe, between southeastern Poland, southwestern Belarus, and western Ukraine. The borders of the region are not clearly defined, but the territory that still carries the name is Volyn Oblast, in western Ukraine.

Comment: Thanks for replying so long since the original post. Can you explain in more detail how you understood "Omriau Amriau" to be a place in Wolin? Or are these other names for Wolin?